# How to get the duration of an inserted time by inserting another one with minute:seconds:milliseconds?

Tags: php

I am making a game mode in which I am trying to get the time a player has arrived at their destination after starting the mode and to do this I am using the insert of a date when it starts the mode it inserts a date and after reaching the your destination it registers another date and with both dates it calculates the time it took to get to the destination, with this I'm using date H:i:s (hours, minutes, seconds) but I need to take the time out and leave milliseconds after seconds example: i:s:u (minutes, seconds, milliseconds) but I'm not able to do this, I've tried it in several ways, basically everything works as follows:

**1.** I add in the player array a current date with hour, minutes, seconds;

```
$this->game[$player->getName()] = ["start" => strtotime('now')];
```

**2.** After the Player arrives at his destination he calculates the time of his trajectory creating another current date with already registered and using date and mktime to do the join and give a visual of time to the player;

```
$time = date('H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, str_replace("-", "", $this->game[$player->getName()]["start"] - strtotime('now'))));
```

**3.** Send the pretty message to the player about the time of his trajectory then time will be something like this: 01:45:23 (minute:seconds:milliseconds).

```
$player->sendMessage("You beat your time record by ".$time);
```

This is my method of doing, if you have another better method with the milli seconds added I accept the suggestion! Maybe there might be some errors in my code that I'm still not sure if they work correctly as the subtraction to calculate and join the current time with the previous one, tell me if it's right and if it is not correct correct me or do better. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `microtime` which returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds

```
$game = [];

$game['start'] = microtime(true);
// Do stuff
sleep(3); // Without the sleep, start and end are the 'same'
$game['end'] = microtime(true);

$elapsedTime = ($game['end'] - $game['start']);

$minutes = floor($elapsedTime / 60);
$seconds = $elapsedTime % 60;
$milliseconds = number_format($elapsedTime - floor($elapsedTime),3);
```

Comment: so when i do that i receive numbers like this > -39.905441045761 how do i convert to 00:00:00 (minutes:seconds:milliseconds)? What is the best way for that.

Comment: I used your changes and now it gets like this > Minutes: -1 Seconds: -17 Miliseconds: 0.350